# virtualbox screen goes black when rebooting

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

WHen rebooting my windows xp virtualbox VM, the screen goes blank with the top 1/2 of the screen having slanted lines all over it.

it only seems to happen if I reboot and minimize the window, if I keep the focus on that window it doesn't happend.

I have to go to machines -> reset to fix it.

Comment: what host os? and which version of virtualbox do you use?

Answer (score 1):

There are usually a few solutions for the screen hanging on a reboot:

- Give the guest a little more memory
- Disable **Nested Paging** in settings
- Disable **Auto resize guest display** in settings

The slanted lines are likely from the auto resizing of the display.

Comment: what is nested paging?

Comment: It is specific to AMD-V and Core i7, so it may not be of interest to you depending on what processor you have.